# What to do when your users get hacked

Tags: asp.net, authentication, openid

I've been seeing a trend in my log files recently of user agent "Microsoft URL Control - 6.01.9782" causing issues. When I trace the IP it comes from China or India. Our website is very local specific so we get very few visitors from outside of the city.

The interesting thing that's new is that I'm seeing a valid logged in user via openID. My guess as to what is happening is that the users computers cookies are being cloned and a virus is hijacking the session. I'm using built in asp.net authentication to handle my cookies and Microsoft doesn't include any checks for IP or user agent so I know I can copy cookies and forge a log in.

I have seen both Google and Facebook accounts log in like this.

My questions are:

A) Is there an easy way to make asp.net authentication more secure?

B) What should I do about these accounts? (best practice) I don't collect any personal information and have no way to contact some of my users.

Comment: Jokes aside, you can drop the session/cookie and serve a captcha challenge to make sure that it's not an automated attack. If the user has been compromised and there is an actual person that's pretending to be the user, then you're not going to have much luck.

Comment: I know these are bots. They likely won't do much damage while logged in as they seem to just be crawling links and most changes require javascript. My biggest concern is that the system , if compromised could really be life or death for my users. My hope is there is some hidden high security asp.net I could turn on that would track for ip changes.

Comment: **Really** life or death?? Then you better figure out a better way to do security!

Comment: It's an emergency alert system used by the fire department.  At least one part of it is. It's designed to provide vital information to users in an emergency. Supplementing radio broadcasts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HttpOnly that prevents client-side script from accessing the cookie via the document.cookie property. Cookies will still roundtrip but will be inaccessible by scripts and will not be stolen.

With ASP.NET 1.1, add in Global.asax the code bellow:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    foreach(string cookie in Response.Cookies)    
    {        
        const string HTTPONLY = ";HttpOnly";        
        string path = Response.Cookies[cookie].Path;       
        if (path.EndsWith(HTTPONLY) == false)       
        {            
            //force HttpOnly to be added to the cookie           
            Response.Cookies[cookie].Path += HTTPONLY;        
        }    
    }
}
```

With ASP.NET 2.0 and above, you can use the web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
</system.web>
```

If the security is something very important in your system, a better approach is to invest in a SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) connection to your site. You can then set a cookie property that causes the cookie to be transmitted only if a SSL connection is present. SSL does not protect the cookie from being read or manipulated while it is on the user's computer, but it does prevent the cookie from being read while in transit because the cookie is encrypted. 
This approach requires the acquisition of a SSL certificate.

This can be done in the httpcookies element of web.config.

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
</system.web>
```

If the connection is not SSL the cookie is not sent to the server.

See more:

[ASP.NET Cookies FAQ](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/asp-net/198ce250-59da-4388-89e5-fce33d725aa7/aspnet-cookies-faq.aspx)

[Design and Deploy Secure Web Apps with ASP.NET 2.0 and IIS 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163702.aspx)

Comment: Great feedback. Sadly I can't use https because the CMS software that powers most of the site doesn't support it (it hard codes all links to http). I'd actually never heard of httpOnly cookieshttps://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

Comment: I don't think I can implement this as we use "FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie" to create our auth cookie and other cookies do need to be read by javascript. Asp.net seems to be either all cookies in the web config or you have to create them all and not use any built in helpers or controls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about the security boundaries here.  If an end-user's PC is compromised, there is *nothing* that you can do on your site to make 100% sure that an attacker cannot behave as that user.  A well engineered piece of malware can fully operate as the user, see anything they see, and capture anything, including passwords, that they type.

The **responsible** thing to do, and in fact what sites like google do, is to notify the user that their account was accessed from a suspect IP and give them links to information on how to clean their PC, change their password on all sites (especially their email provider) and prevent identity theft.  You can do this via a batch job, flagging their accounts and popping up a bright red warning sign when they next log in, or even sending them an email letting them know what's up.

Comment: Great feedback. I guess my trouble is these users use OpenID so they aren't really my user accounts.  Informing my users when they return is hard to do as my site gets very few return logins.

Comment: I don't know OpenID at all, but assuming that they use email address identifiers it seems pretty straightforward.  Notifying the service provider that they use for their OpenID is another responsible path.